# Hibernate Complex query through many Entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Java-SE 1.6/JPA application that uses Hibernate 3.6 to perform persistence. Such an application has a domain model like shown below (in a simplified form):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    // many fields, getters and setters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Enrollment> enrollments = new ArrayList<Enrollment>();
    public Collection<Enrollment> getEnrollments() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(enrollments);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "enrollments")
public class Enrollment implements Serializable {

    // many fields, getters and setters

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    @OneToOne
    private Course course;
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course implements Serializable {

    // many fields, getters and setters

}
```

So, in plain english, this model enable us to model the following domain rule:

*"A given student can have a number of enrollments in a number of courses at the same time."*

Everything is working splendidly until now. The question here is:

*"How to select all the students who have enrollments in a given course?"*

So, I have a instance of `Course` and my job is to select all the instances of `Student` that are (indirectly) related to that `Course` (through instances of `Enrollment`) by using a Hibernate query.

Could someone give me some advices and/or ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using `criteria`?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the chapter on HQL and joins in the hibernate documentation?

Comment: I have read about HQL and Criteria, but not deeply. Before going to an extensive reading and testing I decided to ask the question and get directions. Is one better than the other for this particular problem?

Comment: Criteria is used to dynamically create queries based on multiple optional... criteria. For a static query, HQL is much simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select s from Student s join s.enrollments e join e.course c where c.id = :courseId
```

Using criteria

```
List<Student> students = session.createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("enrollments", "e").createAlias("e.course", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", courseId)).list();
```